# How can I get this display to show in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js

Ok So what setting or plugin will give me this output when I hover over my "videos" element in VSCode? I can see it here in this screenshot of a YouTube tutorial, but I don't get this popup on my VScode as I follow along with the same code...

[image]

// settings.json location on a *nix system
Contents of my ~/Home/.config/Code/User/settings.json

```
{
  "editor.fontSize": 16,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.parameterHints.cycle": false,
  "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "midnight blue",
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
  "interactiveSession.editor.fontSize": 16,
  "markdown.preview.fontSize": 16,
  "tailwindCSS.rootFontSize": 18,
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {},
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "terminal.integrated.persistentSessionScrollback": 300,
  "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
  "editor.hover.enabled": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.enableDebugLogs": true,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "javascript.format.enable": false,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "[prisma]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Prisma.prisma"
  },
  "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
  "todohighlight.isEnable": true,
  "todohighlight.include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.html",
    "**/*.css",
    "**/*.scss",
    "**/*.php",
    "**/*.rb",
    "**/*.txt",
    "**/*.mdown",
    "**/*.md",
    "**/*.vue"
  ],
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
  },
  "javascript.inlayHints.functionLikeReturnTypes.enabled": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to the two commenters I was pushed to locate the system settings.json file (not the one locally located in the project at .vscode/settings.json). Systematically testing each "false" value to find which one affected my desired outcome led me to "editor.hover.enabled" which needed to be set to "true".